# what UINavigationController do with object which calls pushViewController: function?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Is it removes object from superview or just hides that object?

Comment: If you mean what happens to viewController that is already pushed to stack than - to answer your question navigationController "hides" it.
Controller's view disappears, but stays loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs :) Its adding it to the stack, not removing it. `popViewControllerAnimated:` removes it.

> The object in the viewController parameter becomes the top view
>   controller on the navigation stack. Pushing a view controller results
>   in the display of the view it manages. How that view is displayed is
>   determined by the animated parameter. If the animated parameter is
>   YES, the view is animated into position; otherwise, the view is simply
>   displayed in place. The view is automatically resized to fit between
>   the navigation bar and toolbar (if present) before it is displayed.
>
> In addition to displaying the view associated with the new view
>   controller at the top of the stack, this method also updates the
>   navigation bar and tool bar accordingly. In iOS 3.0 and later, the
>   contents of the built-in navigation toolbar are updated to reflect the
>   toolbar items of the new view controller. For information on how the
>   navigation bar is updated, see “Updating the Navigation Bar.”

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated: